# Trademark infringement in display names of user accounts

Tags: support

I came across a user account bearing the name of one of the Ubuntu flavours.  I was not aware of Xubuntu operating its own team account and [this one](https://askubuntu.com/users/903128/xubuntu) uses the flavour's name.  I've pinged the team in its IRC channel to ask if this is something they're operating but this may be [a trademarks infringement](https://ubuntu.com/legal/trademarks) against Canonical if not connected to the development team.

Comment: Really? Don't you think that is a bit of a over reaction to a user name (on Ask Ubuntu no less). I see people all over the internet with brand names in their user names and never see company's complain, if anything it is free advertising for them. Are you going to go through every user on this site and find all the ones with Ubuntu in their usernames and report them too? because there are thousands of them. What utter nonsense :(

Comment: I think it reflects badly on SE that official flavors/names particularly with meaning on the site, can be usurped by users. I don't think it reflects well on the person who took it, who I assume was young thus acted first without thinking, but I for one agree with Stephen.

Comment: @guiverc It is not really usurped, user names can be identical on SE, if XUbuntu really wanted an official presence on here, they could still use that user name as users are identified by their ID. The problem with this post is what a massive overreaction it is to try to report a user (who in no way claims any association with XUbuntu and is not a company trading anything) for trademark infringement based off of a user name that they likely took out of a love for the product. FYI three users have that name on the site and eleven have solely Ubuntu as their name, if anyone cared....

Comment: ...or this was some kind of violation then action would of been taken already. You can search for users by name here: https://askubuntu.com/users feel free to report every one of them.

Comment: Trademark Infringement is not something the moderator team cares about (that's best left to SE Staff/Legal).  If you have this type of concern you should take this up with the Canonical Legal Team and let them determine if it's actual trademark infringement.  The use of a trademarked name in a username does *not* reflect an official use of the trademark towards infringement under most trademark laws and therefore wouldn't necessarily be a violation of the trademark. (This is something ***lawyers*** need to handle however, so...)

Comment: (Note I am not a lawyer, but I've done multiple studies into trademark infringement per my college coursework and evaluation of current laws and regulations so I have a pretty good grasp on it)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Possible copyright or trademark infringements should be brought to the attention of the copyright or trademark holder.

It then becomes their problem to deal with how they see fit.

If they want the offending post, image, username or whatever removed then they can contact Stack Exchange.

It's not our place, as users or moderators, to police this.